# How MCMT is implemented in Qiskit, what is the initiution behind it?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-control

I have read about and used the [MCMT qiskit gate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.MCMT.html) (Multiple Control Multiple Target).
But I wonder how they have implemented it, how is a gate (like CCCZ for example) is decopmosed into basic gates and constructed using MCMT? What is the initiution behind it? is there a base paper that describes how to do such thing?